# Update records matched and unmatched?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a TSQL stored procedure that does an UPDATE to a table where certain criteria must be matched.  This updates a "ProcessDate" to GETDATE().  However, all unmatched data never gets this ProcessDate updated (since there was no match it stays a NULL).  Is there a way to update the ProcessDate on the records that do not match at the same time?  My current solution would be to simply add an additional UPDATE statement after the first one runs to go back and update all ProcessDate = NULL to GETDATE(), but wasn't sure if there was a better way of doing this or not?  Thank you.

Comment: Why not just change your join to `ON target.key = src.key OR target.ProcessDate IS NULL`?

Comment: I guess you need to give some data to illustrate what you mean. I read your post at least 3 times, and still do not get what you mean, because to me, your all records can be classified as two categories, 1. records matched 2. records NOT matched, and you want to update records in both categories, then why not just update all records without any where clause? Something must be wrong here

Comment: You'll get more helpful information if you start here [How to post a T-SQL question on a public forum](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) so that we have more to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you could use a MERGE, with a section for WHEN MATCHED, and a section for WHEN NOT MATCHED.  You can control which UPDATE applies to which situation.  If you provide the queries you have so far, I can help create the MERGE if needs be.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `case` and move your selection criteria there from the `where` part:

```
update t set ProcessDate = case
    when <MyCriteriaMet> then getdate()
    else @MyOtherValue
end
from dbo.MyTable t;
```